# How to use :value and v-model together

Tags: vue.js

I need to use :value and v-model together. I've got a form and on the following component I'm receiving an 'age' as a query parameter because I'm filling a previous input somewhere else. I want that age to auto-populate the input on this component. But what if the user changes that value? I'd like to re-store that new age and emit it to the parent .Vue file. How can I do this?

In other words: what if I'm getting a '3' as the age, the auto-populated input shows a '3' but then the user notices they wanted to write '30' instead of '3'? How can I save 30 instead of '3'?

Thanks in advance

```html
<template>
  <div>
      <p>age</p>
      <input type="text" :value="age" v-model="age_keyup" @keyup="send()">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      age_keyup: null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send(){
       this.$emit("age_keyup", this.age);
    }
  },
  props: ['age']
}
</script>
```

Comment: why did you remove the accept from my answer?

Answer (score 3):

No need to bind the value to that prop just init `age_keyup` based on `age` :

```
<template>
  <div>
      <p>age</p>
      <input type="text"  v-model="age_keyup" @keyup="send()">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: function () {
    return {
      age_keyup:null,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    send(){
       this.$emit("age_keyup", this.age_keyup);
    }
  },
  props: ['age'],
   mounted(){
     this.age_keyup=this.age
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: do you want that your component to be two-way bound with parent one?